# mysql, how to set a column default value current year

Tags: mysql

the table looks like this:

```
id----name-----value-----year
1-----ab-------10-------2014
2-----ab-------10-------2014
```

for example now the defalt time is change means the year has changed current system year.

here the entry is only (**Insert into table ('id','name','value') value ('3','adfaf','20')**

here i want the year column to get default year only from the system time so when i run the upper query the result should be bellow as the system year now is 2015 so the column year get the year form the system. if i set the year to timestamp or current time it get all the value of time and date but i want only year.

```
3---adfaf---20-2015
```

the year column is current default year.

how to alter my table so i get the result.

regards

Comment: You cannot do this with data type `YEAR` because of MySQL limitations, but you may consider using `TIMESTAMP` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_year
BEFORE INSERT ON tableNAME
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.year = YEAR(NOW());
```

Comment: What if the row has an explicit year set already? This will override it. A default should only be used when you don't specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to make the default automatically be the current year. You could use an `INSERT` trigger that sets the year to the current year if it's `NULL`. Or at the beginning of each year you can manually change the default:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable MODIFY year INT DEFAULT 2015;
```

Comment: column should get the default year from system it must not be static

Comment: You understand that MySQL doesn't allow the DEFAULT option to be an expression, don't you? There's a special case for using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for columns with datatype `TIMESTAMP`, but all other defaults have to be static.

Comment: but the trigger worked for me, thanks form your anser